# How is the validity of pointer comparisons within an array ensured?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, runtime

The C standard guarantees the validity of a pointer comparison when both point to elements of the same array, but how does that typically get ensured in a system?

The compiler might let you choose between signed and unsigned pointers.  The compiler will be generating the assembly that does the comparison.  But the compiler does not allocate the memory.  For example, if you compile with signed pointers, how does the compiler know the runtime won't allocate a block for an array that spans the signed overflow break?

Comment: "signed pointers"?  [Citation needed]

Comment: Do you mean when converting an *integer* for use as a *pointer*? (And, ick!)

Answer (score 1):

> The compiler might let you choose between signed and unsigned pointers. The compiler will be generating the assembly that does the comparison. But the compiler does not allocate the memory. For example, if you compile with signed pointers, how does the compiler know the runtime won't allocate a block for an array that spans the signed overflow break?

In other words, how does a typical implementation ensure that no user data spans address `0x80000000` or `0x00000000`. Well, on the popular desktop operating systems, you get this guarantee for free, because `0x00000000` is in kernel space (inaccessible to your userspace programs) and `0x80000000` is... well, I don't actually know about 32-bit machines anymore. But on a 64-bit machine, `0x8000000000000000` is literally in the middle of nowhere — typical 64-bit OSes don't map *anything at all* in the gigantic range between `0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF` and `0xFFFF000000000000` [(source)](http://www.codemachine.com/article_x64kvas.html). If you have tons of resources, then it's no problem at all to leave a few billion bytes unused. *(Massive understatement alert!)*

Now, if you're programming on bare metal, then you might *not* be guaranteed that `&a[7] < &a[8]`. This is particularly likely to be true if you're programming on a RISC target such as PowerPC or V800 and taking advantage of the "Small Data Area" located around address `0x0000` (which is quick to access because loading from those addresses doesn't require indirection through a register). In this situation, you're basically *encouraging* the compiler to split a variable across the `0x0000` boundary (and even worse, allow `&v == NULL` to be true), in exchange for a valuable optimization.

Answer (score 0):

There are *no* mechanisms to enforce such correctness in C. It is *up to you* to write correct code. C is not a safe language. It is possible to write syntactically correct code that does not form a valid program.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, memory addresses are always used unsigned. If your code uses them otherwise, it's not going to work well (unless you really know what you're doing).

Comment: Most compilers have command-line switches to toggle between "signed pointer comparisons" and "unsigned pointer comparisons". Portable code shouldn't care, but systems code (which non-portably compares unrelated pointers to raw memory) often does care.